# ValueError: Calling `Model.fit` in graph mode is not supported when the `Model` instance was constructed with eager mode enabled

Tags: deep-learning, model, valueerror

```
for i in range(epochs):
  gen = data_generator(train_descriptions,encoding_train,word_to_idx,max_len,batch_size)
  model.fit(gen,epochs=1,steps_per_epoch=steps,verbose=1)
  model.save("best_model.h5")
```

> ValueError: Calling Model.fit in graph mode is not supported when
> the Model instance was constructed with eager mode enabled. Please
> construct your Model instance in graph mode or call Model.fit with
> eager mode enabled.

How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
model.compile(run_eagerly=True)
```

If that doesn't work, you can try to force it after the model compiles:

```
model.compile()
model.run_eagerly = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem is exactly as it tells you.
TensorFlow shifted to Eager Mode starting from version 2.0 and were using Graph Mode in v1.0 .
To solve this issue, check if you have a module/function that invokes TF1.0 behavior.